# How to install Pinegrow 3.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.2?

Tags: unity, launcher

**How to install Pinegrow 3.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.2?**
Pinegrow has changed the way the packaged .zip file gets installed.
I cannot find a .deb file and cannot seem to run program from command line.
I can't figure out how to get a launcher or find program in Unity search.
I cannot find install instructions on Pinegrow website or support area of their website.

Comment: You need to post a question and an answer.  Don't combine them just into one 'question' - ask the question, then answer your own question with your solution.

Comment: Ah...OK, sorry still learning my way around.

Answer (score 0):

> Originally posted by **[burliway777](https://askubuntu.com/users/706513/burliway777)** as part of their question instead of as an answer.

Here are the steps I have performed:

**Pinegrow Linux Install on Ubuntu 16.04**

**Verified Install on: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS**
*Unofficial and Not Supported method of installing Pinegrow 3.0
*Please read comments of users before doing the install as I am a hobbyist Linux user and others may provide more advanced, better or correct way of doing things.
There may be corrections to syntax or command line errors.
*I apologize in advance for using my Google drive for files and will modify the post once I get a better public repository to store the files.

- This guide helps to get Pinegrow 3.0 installed, search-able via Unity Search “Pinegrow”, shows
  Pinegrow Icon, and allow drag n drop of launch icon to launcher bar.
- This guide does not address command line execution of Pinegrow or getting PATH set correctly.

**This method of installing Pinegrow on Ubuntu Linux will:**

- Create a top level folder in /opt named Pinegrow to store Pinegrow Installed Versions
- Create a sub folder in /opt/Pinegrow named 3.0 to hold v3.0 self-contained application
- Modify the Pinegrow.desktop file in the extracted , downloaded .zip file
- Add a Pinegrow “pinegrow.png” icon file to root of the extracted folder
- copy extracted and modified folder contents to /opt/Pinegrow
- mv Pinegrow.desktop to /usr/share/applications

**Pre-install checks:**

In Terminal run:
Note: This command verifies version of Ubuntu

`lsb_release -a`

Note-Output should be something like below.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

In Terminal run: `uname -a`

Output of command we are looking for:

`86_64 GNU/Linux`

Note: The 64 indicating 64bit

So, we now know that we are running on Ubuntu 16.04.2 and have 64bit support.

2:) Download the PinegrowLinux64.3.0.zip file
current URL is:
https://pinegrow.com/
click download button

3:) Right-Click on downloaded xx.ZIP file
select “Extract Here”

4:) [Download](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2M250NGrS0hOU13UHNsR1BCTnc?usp=sharing) and move pinegrow.png to root level of extracted folder
See Google Drive folder for screen-shot file structure that should be in `/opt/Pinegrow/3.0` as example directory structure.

5:) Right-click and Rename extracted folder from `PinegrowLinux64.3.0` to `3.0`

6:) Type in terminal:

```
cd ~  
cd /opt  
sudo mkdir Pinegrow  
cd Pinegrow  
mv ~/Downloads/3.0 .  
Cd 3.0  
sudo nano Pinegrow.desktop
```

Copy and paste code in the example file ( Same location shared on Google drive link ) into the Pinegrow.desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Name=Pinegrow  
GenericName=HTML Editor  
Comment=Create Awesome Websites with Pinegrow  
Exec=sh -c "/opt/Pinegrow/3.0/PinegrowLibrary"  
Icon=/opt/Pinegrow/3.0/pinegrow.png  
Terminal=false  
Type=Application
```

*Make sure to not add it, but let it be the only lines in the file

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save file.

press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save as default listed name (`Pinegrow.desktop`)

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> on keyboard to exit and go back to command prompt

```
sudo mv Pinegrow.desktop /usr/share/applications
```

- Final Notes before any revision or comments: I think all these steps are correct and it brings the desired results, excluding any typing errors.
- As a novice Linux user I did perform what is believe to be un-needed steps which was changing /opt/Pinegrow and /opt/Pinegrow/3.0 permissions using chmod 777 on the folders, but not sub dirs or files.
- I did not make any changes to .profile, .bashrc or other PATH related files.
- So far in testing-Working as desired and expected
- Someone really cool make have time to make this a lot easier and get a script made for this. If no one has time for that at least most of the steps and pain has been alleviated for others.